# XMonad error: xmonad-x86_64-openbsd: executeFile: Permission Denied

Tags: openbsd, xmonad

I'm running *openbsd-6.3* with *xmonad-0.13*, I've tried using `chmod -R +x` on the *.xmonad* directory but when I use `startx` I get the error in the title. The *xmonad.hs* file also compiles with no warnings, but `xmonad --restart` gives the same error. While `xmonad` will run, it just won't use my *xmonad.hs* file!

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the output of `which xmonad`, and `ls -al $(which xmonad)`?

Comment: *which xmonad* gives */usr/local/bin/xmonad* and *ls -al $(which xmonad)* returns *-rwxr-xr-x 1 root bin 3212792 Mar 28 06.52 /usr/local/bin/xmonad*

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenBSD as a desktop: cannot get xmonad fully running](https://www.reddit.com/r/openbsd/comments/7f7l0l/openbsd_as_a_desktop_cannot_get_xmonad_fully/):

> add wxallowed to /etc/fstab for /home.